# Generic protocol method swift can't recognise type as type

Tags: swift, generics, swift3, polymorphism, swift-protocols

I have created a generic view controller to pick an item from a list and I want to use a generic delegate method to return the item which has been selected. My setup is as follows:

```
class ListPickerViewController<T>: UIViewController {
    var delegate: ListPickerViewControllerDelegate?
}

protocol ListPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    func listPickerViewControllerDelegate<T>(_ listPickerViewController: ListPickerViewController<T>, selectedItem: T)
}
```

I have a list of objects which I will use to populate a ListPickerViewController

```
class MyClass {
    let a = "sometext"
}
```

In the class I want to get the selected item from I implement the method and give the selected item delegate a type parameter for the type of objects in the list.

```
func listPickerViewControllerDelegate<MyClass>(_ listPickerViewController: ListPickerViewController<MyClass>, selectedItem: MyClass) {
    print(selectedItem.a)
}
```

This doesn't compile however! I get an error 'Value of type MyClass has no member a'. So I tried casting it to the type

```
func listPickerViewControllerDelegate<MyClass>(_ listPickerViewController: ListPickerViewController<MyClass>, selectedItem: MyClass) {
    let selected = selectedItem as! MyClass
}
```

This gives 'Force cast of MyClass to same type has no effect'.

For some reason I've found that this works:

```
typealias MyClassAlias = MyClass 

func listPickerViewControllerDelegate<MyClass>(_ listPickerViewController: ListPickerViewController<MyClass>, selectedItem: MyClass) {
    let selected = selectedItem as MyClassAlias
    print(selected.a) // works
}
```

Surely there's a better way? Or is this a shortcoming of swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the signature of the delegate method in your protocol implementation `MyClass` is just a generic parameter, you could have used `T`, `K`, etc.  It doesn't necessarily have a member named `a`, hence the first compilation error.  In

```
let selected = selectedItem as! MyClass
```

it is just force-cast to its own type, which could be pretty much anything.  `MyClass` used in the body of the delegate method is the generic parameter used in the function signature, not the `MyClass` class that has the `a` member.

If you use the typealias, then it can be used in the body of the method and it compiles, but as soon as the actual type of the `MyClass` generic parameter is changed to something other than `MyClass` class, the cast will fail at runtime.

In general you are likely to need a separate delegate protocol implementation for each type of selected object.  I'm assuming that the generic parameter `T` of the view controller is the selected object type.  You also need to make sure that a type-specific view controller uses the right delegate implementation.

In Swift you can use associated types to accomplish this.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html.

The view controller and delegate protocol might look like this:

```
    class ListPickerViewController<T, D : ListPickerViewControllerDelegate>
    : UIViewController
    where D.T == T
    {
        var delegate: D?
    ......
    }

    protocol ListPickerViewControllerDelegate {
        associatedtype T
        func listPickerViewControllerDelegate<D>(_ controller: 
ListPickerViewController<T, D>, selectedItem: T) where D.T == T
    }
```

A delegate implementation for use with selected items of type `MyClass` might look as follows:

```
    class MyDelegateImpl : ListPickerViewControllerDelegate {
        typealias T = MyClass

        internal func listPickerViewControllerDelegate<D>(_ controller: 
ListPickerViewController<MyClass, D>, selectedItem: MyClass) 
    where D.T == MyClass {
            print("In the delegate method!")
            print("MyClass.a = \(selectedItem.a)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry - I meant to remove WBSCode and replace with MyClass, updated now

Comment: The explanation of why MyClass is referring to <MyClass> and not the actual class makes sense. How can we then tell swift what the type of this method should be? Or - is it just always of a generic type, and it's up to you to cast it?